# Trying to write a function which adds all values in a list except the lowest number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to write a function in python which takes

```
a = ("list", [4, 5, 2, 6, 2, 3])
```

adds all the numbers but discounts the lowest number, in this case only one of the two's should not be added. So it should be doing

```
4 + 5 + 2 + 6 + 3 = 20
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `sum(sorted(your_list[1:]))` should do it. Strange that you're replicating built-in functionality though, and there's no evidence that you've even started. This has all the feel of homework. I'll leave this foolishness here, but well done @rassar

Comment: @Andrew I think your parentheses are off, it should be `sum(sorted(your_list)[1:])`

Comment: Good spot rassar

Comment: Sorting is overkill for an application like this, since it takes O(n lg n) time but you can find the minimum in O(n).

Comment: you can use the function "sorted()" to sort your list. Then, I am sure you can code it by yourself.

Comment: Do you always ignore exactly one occurrence of the minimum, or do you keep one occurrence of the minimum?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the `sum()` and `min()` functions:

```
def f(a):
    return sum(a[1]) - min(a[1])

a =  ("list", [4, 5, 2, 6, 2, 3])
print(f(a))  # 20
```